# How to run synchronous hooks on feathersjs

Tags: feathersjs

I am trying to run two hooks synchronously on Feathersjs but the "addHost" function called by the statement "hook.service.find({ query: { active: '1' } }).then(page => page.data.forEach(addHost));" in the first hook is executing after the second hook. I need that all statements in hook1 finished before starting hook2. What I am doing wrong? thanks in advance!
My code is the following:

**Hook1:**

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return function hook1 (hook) {
    hook.service.find({ query: { active: '1' } }).then(page => page.data.forEach(addHost));
  };
};

function addHost(client) {
  /* Some code here.... */
  console.log('This code is executing at the end');
}
```

**Hook2:**

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return function hook2 (hook) {
    /* Some code here.... */
    console.log('This code is executing first');
  };
};
```

**xxx.hooks.js file**

```
module.exports = {
  /* Some code here.... */

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [hook1(), hook2()],
    update: [],
    patch: [hook1(), hook2()],
    remove: []
  },

  /* Some code here.... */

};
```

**Output:**

This code is executing first

This code is executing at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the hook to execute synchronously but you want the asynchronous operation to finish before continuing on. This can be done by returning a Promise [as documented in the asynchronous hook API docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#asynchronous-hooks) in your case like this:

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return function hook1 (hook) {
    return hook.service.find({ query: { active: '1' } })
      .then(page => page.data.forEach(addHost))
      .then(() => {
        // Always return the `hook` object or `undefined`
        return hook;
      });
  };
};
```